# access stored values from a tableViewCell and save them to firebaseDatabase

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, slider

I have a tableViewCell that has a range slider inside of it. I would like the values from the range slider to be saved to firebase when the user hits handleSave(). I can print out the values when the user slides the range slider inside the tableViewCell, but I cannot save this value from the tableViewCell itself nor can I print the values from the tableViewVC. When I try to print the values from the tableViewVC I don't see anything in my console. But If I were to print them from my tableViewCell itself then it works just fine.

The code that I am using to try and print the values from my tableViewVC is,

```
   if indexPath.section == 2 {
        
        let costRangeCell = AgeRangeCell(style: .default, reuseIdentifier: nil)
        costRangeCell.rangeSlider.minimumValue = 5
        costRangeCell.rangeSlider.maximumValue = 200
        costRangeCell.rangeSlider.lowValue = 5
        costRangeCell.rangeSlider.highValue = 200
        costRangeCell.rangeSlider.minimumDistance = 20
        costRangeCell.delegate = self
        
        return costRangeCell
    }


var lowCost: Double = 0.0
var highCost: Double = 0.0

func didChange(lowVal: Double, highVal: Double, forCell cell: AgeRangeCell) {
    self.lowCost = lowVal
    self.highCost = highVal
}
```

in the above print statements, I can see the value of the range slider that the user has chosen.

and how I plan to save the data is in the tableViewVc as well.

```
    @objc fileprivate func handleSave() {
       guard let uid = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid else { return }
    let docData: [String: Any] = [
        "minSeekingCost": lowCost,
        "maxSeekingCost": highCost
        
    ]
    
    self.updateUserDataIntoDatabseWithUID(uid: uid, values: docData as [String : AnyObject])
    print("Finished saving user info")
    self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: {
        print("Dismissal complete")
        print(lowVal)
        print(highVal)
    })
}
```

when I try to see what the value is being printed here, it just shows 0 and 1 not the actual number of the rangeSlider

```
   protocol AgeRangeCellDelegate {
func didChange(lowVal: Double, highVal: Double, forCell cell: AgeRangeCell)
 }

 class AgeRangeCell: UITableViewCell {

let rangeSlider: AORangeSlider = {
    let slider = AORangeSlider()
    slider.stepValue = 5
    slider.trackColor = GREEN_Theme
    slider.addTarget(self, action: #selector(didChangeCost), for: .touchUpInside)
    return slider
}()

var delegate: AgeRangeCellDelegate?
var user: User?
let lowLabel = UILabel()
let highLabel = UILabel()

override init(style: UITableViewCell.CellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
    super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
    commonInit()
}

@objc func didChangeCost(_ sender: AORangeSlider) {
    delegate?.didChange(lowVal: sender.lowValue, highVal: sender.highValue, forCell: self)
        }

required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: coder)

   }

 }
```

When the print statement is inside of the ageRangeCell, I can successfully print the values of the range slider. But when I try to print the rangeSliders value inside of the tableViewVC it is not working. The only way for me to save this information to firebase is if I had access to its value. What am I missing? If I can print the statements inside of the tableViewVC I can then save them to the database.

Comment: As always, a cell is an object to display data, nothing else. it's not a place to store something. If the cell contains UI elements which modify the data source you are responsible to update the model. Then get the data from the **model**, not from the **view**. And you are strongly discouraged from creating cells with the designated initializer in a table view. Reuse them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Issues with your code

1. In **handelSave** method when you trying to get value from the cell you are expecting to get slider values which user made, but in reality you are creating new instance of **AgeRangeCell** with default values. To solve this problem you need to use **delegation** pattern as I did post it.

   Delete this line in the handleSave method:
   **let costRangeCell = AgeRangeCell(style: .default, reuseIdentifier: nil)**

   For minSeekingCost & maxSeekingCost values in the class it must be created additional parameter to hold this values.
2. When creating **AgeRangeCell** you are not passing reuse identifier and it can lead slow table view scrolling performance.

#### Possible solutions

1. Use MVC and delegation patter. You need to have value holder for your age. Below is example how it can be achieved.
2. Build UI using **SwiftUI**. Together with **Combine** it allows eliminate delegation pattern.

I did use storyboard for this reason less code needed.

### AgeRangeCell and AgeRangeCellDelegate

```
protocol AgeRangeCellDelegate {
    func didChange(age: Float, forCell cell: AgeRangeCell)
}

class AgeRangeCell: UITableViewCell {
    
    var delegate: AgeRangeCellDelegate?
    
    @IBOutlet weak var slider: UISlider!
    
    @IBAction func didChangeAge(_ sender: UISlider) {
        delegate?.didChange(age: sender.value, forCell: self)
    }
}
```

### ViewController

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
    
    var age: Float = 0
    
    @IBAction func didTapSave(_ sender: Any) {
        // TODO: Save age to Firestore
        
        guard let uid = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid else { return }
        let docData: [String: Any] = [
            "age": age
        ]
        
        updateUserDataIntoDatabseWithUID(uid: uid, values: docData as [String : AnyObject])
    }
}
```

### UITableViewDataSource

```
extension ViewController: UITableViewDataSource {
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        1
    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "AgeRangeCell") as! AgeRangeCell
        
        cell.delegate = self
        cell.slider.value = age
        
        return cell
    }
}
```

### AgeRangeCellDelegate

```
extension ViewController: AgeRangeCellDelegate {
    func didChange(age: Float, forCell cell: AgeRangeCell) {
        self.age = age
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this, I am trying to understand the process and apply to my application. but I am still having issues. For instance,  I am using a rangeSlider that has two handles and how would I get the values from both? I just don't get why I can print the values, inside fo the indexPath section, but I can't get the same values to store

Comment: Is there a more simple way to store this value?

Comment: I am still facing same issue. I think the disconnect may be with me trying to implement your answer via code

Comment: I don't understand how I can print the low and high values inside of the indexPath into the console but not store the value when its saved.

Comment: You can share somewhere the code. I will take a look.

Comment: I have updated my code in my question with the changes I have made. I would like to award you the bounty. Could you take a quick look for me and let me know whats being missed?

Comment: Added comment to **Issues with your code** section.

Comment: I have made a quick edit as you were sending that update! I feel like we are moving in the same direction but I am still having issues. :( The edit I made were brief changes and code cuts.

Comment: I can't really spot differences in our code? Other than the implementations are called a little differently.

Comment: This must be done in the AgeRangeCell: costRangeCell.rangeSlider.valuesChangedHandler

Comment: You do not need add target as delegation is used. costRangeCell.rangeSlider.addTarget(self, action: #selector(didChange(lowVal:highVal:forCell:)), for: .valueChanged)

Comment: I have fixed the solution. Your answer helped me get to my conclusion so I will reward you. Thank you.